# Kinetics of Decomposition of Hydrogen Peroxide

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, concentration, chemical-formula

Consider the decomposition of Hydrogen Peroxide:

$$\ce{H2O2 -> H2O + 1/2O2}$$

The  rate law for this reaction is :

$$\text{Rate} = k[\ce{H2O2}]$$

Further
$$\text{Rate} = -\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{H2O2}]}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\mathrm d[\ce{H2O}]}{\mathrm dt} = 2\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{O2}]}{\mathrm dt}\tag1$$

---

Now consider :

$$\ce{2H2O2 -> 2H2O + O2}$$

The  rate law for this reaction is :

$$\text{Rate} = k[\ce{H2O2}]$$

Further
$$\text{Rate} = -\frac {1}{2}\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{H2O2}]}{\mathrm dt} = \frac {1}{2}\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{H2O}]}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\mathrm d[\ce{O2}]}{\mathrm dt}\tag {2}$$

---

My question:

1. Which one is correct - eq $(1)$ or eq $(2)$?
2. What is the general principle for deciding this?

---

### Update:

As I have been informed through comments that both the equations are equally true, I have another doubt:

Consider half-life time of the reaction (first order kinetics):
$$t_{1/2} = \frac {\ln 2}{k}$$

As stated in the comments rate constant of both the reactions denoted by $k_1$ for $eq 1$ and $k_2$ for $eq 2$ are different. This means that the half life time of these reactions are different.

But the half-life time for first order kinetics is independent of initial concentration and no matter what equation we use , the actual reaction happening in the jar is the same. Provided this, how can there two different half-life times?

Comment: Both are correct. Why not?

Comment: As @IvanNeretin said, both eq. are correct. But, both of the reactions can't have the same rate constants. I think this is what you want to ask. ?

Comment: Sure, they are not the same. They are different; they differ by a factor of 2. That's not much of a surprise, since the reactions themselves are different.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So which is more generally accepted or is used in questions?

Comment: There does not seem to be an obvious preference.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sir please see the updated part.

Comment: Try fully solving the whole rate equation.. You should get your mistake.. the effective k here would be same..

Comment: For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)